# Coverflow Layout for FLEX

Tags: actionscript-3, apache-flex, layout, coverflow

I search for good CoverFlow Component/Layout. This one looks very good [3d Horisontal Cover Flow](http://www.flexdownloads.com/preview_source/113/index.html) but I did not find any source for it. Also I found [tink coverflowlayout](http://www.tink.ws/blog/coverflowlayout/) it looks like what I need, but there no swc library for it(It's can be downloaded with source code but in this case so many classes should be copied into project).
Is there any other goood FLEX libraries for Cover Flow?

Comment: Why not take Tink's library; and create your own SWC?

Comment: I think it can solve the problem, but when I tried compile the "tink" library with "compc" I have a lot of compilation errors and I don't know how to fix them now. Sow if there any ready solution (swc, or 1-2 mxml files) it helps a lot.

Comment: Most likely you are missing something from the source path and/or are compiling against a different version of the Flex SDK.

Answer (score 0):

How about FlowGallery? But it looks using Flex SDK3.

http://activeden.net/item/flowgallery/68292/

Comment: This one looks nice, but it is not what I search. It's optimized for big images and big screen. I need a small component(on my window it shold be maximum of 300-400px width. And I want be able to use not only pictures but custom controls to.
Something like this http://www.tink.ws/blog/coverflowlayout/

Thank you for your reply.